# Home exchange sites?

Tags: online-resources, rental, homestay

I'm looking into a home exchange / house exchange deal where I can swap my place with someone else for a month. Does anyone know any good sites for locating other people in the same scenario?

I've used [Airbnb](http://www.airbnb.com/) before and found it great. The fact people can link data to their account or have reviews gives you a little more trust in renting from a stranger.

Comment: Check https://exchangemouse.com to see all of them

Comment: We've done multiple exchanges through homeexchange.com, superb experience!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top-known one that I've heard of is [Home Exchange](http://www.homeexchange.com/).   It's international.  However since I'm renting out my house, I've not done it, personally.

Comment: Thanks - I came across that site. It seemed to be lacking a bit when compared to other sites such as airbnb (No reviews from what I saw etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I think [swapyourhome.net](http://www.swapyourhome.net) is another best home exchange website.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is [www.knok.com](http://www.knok.com) . This is a new alternative with thousands of homes. I joined last year and I already swapped twice: France and Italy, and everything was ok in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Some others you may try are:

- [Digsville](http://www.digsville.com)
- [IHEN](http://www.ihen.com)
- [Intervac](http://www.intervac-homeexchange.com)
- [GTI](http://www.gti-home-exchange.com)
- [Swapnow](http://www.swapnow.com)

Each has a somewhat different flavor. GTI, for example, has an eco-friendly 
appeal.

Answer (score 2):

There are 60+ home exchange sites, and which one is best for you depends heavily on where you live, and where you want to go at the moment. There are big general sites, and lots of country or interest specific ones, like one for LGBT people or Waldorf parents or Aussies. My own project,  https://exchangemouse.com is to navigate all of them. Search in one place, and then go to the original sites to contact chosen homes.

Answer (score 1):

couchsurfing.com may facilitate your aims by putting you in touch with people with travel accommodation requirements. However from a friend who has used it, the impression I get is that it's more about being present in your house where people come to stay. But check it out.